# how to append <li > <a hyperlinks to a php variable?

Tags: php, html, append

I want to construct hyerlinks and append them as shown below .But I get error like this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
```

could any one help me fix this error and append the hyperlinks inside for each loop correctly? Thanks in advance.

php variable to construct but give me error:

```
 <?
    $resultCounter =0;
    $links ="";
    $stringToSearch ="Mango";

    $returnvalues=mysearch($stringToSearch);

    echo $returnvalues[0];  
    echo $returnvalues[1]; 


    function mysearch($stringToSearch)
    {
            ///rest of the code
            foreach ($pieces as $lineNumber => $grouped) 
            {
              if (strpos($grouped[0], $stringToSearch) !== false) 
              {
               $resultCounter++;
             echo "<br>first line:".$grouped[0]."<br>second line:".$grouped[1]."<br>";
               $stream_name = substr($grouped[0],strrpos($grouped[0],',')+1);
               $stream_url = $grouped[1];
               $stream_logo = scrape_value($grouped[0], 'tvg-logo');
               $parsed = get_string_between($stream_logo, '_', '_');

                $links .="<li><a id=\"CH"\".$parsed."\" onclick=\"setMe(false);setCurrentID('".$parsed."');javascript:doit('".$stream_url."','".$stream_logo."',this.id);\">'".$stream_name."'</a><img src=\"".$stream_logo."\" /></li>\n\n";

               }//end of if
            }// end of for each
       return array($links,$resultCounter); 
    }//end of function
        ?>
        <?php echo $links; ?>
```

sample:

```
<li><a id="CH123456" onclick="setMe(false);setCurrentID('123456');javascript:doit('html://somesite.com/','./logos/123456.png',this.id);">test</a><img src="./logos/123456.png"></li>
```

Comment: Change `id=\"CH\".$parsed.\"` in `id=\"CH\"".$parsed."\"`. However, I think that the parse error is not in this line,

Comment: Thanks for replies. fusion3k i updated the code now i don't get any error but the hyperlinks doesn't' get printed. But  echo "<br>first line:".$grouped[0]."<br>second line:".$grouped[1]."<br>"; prints result ! could you tell me what might be wrong?

Comment: @user1788736 Sorry, remove `\"` after `CH`: `id=\"CH".$parsed."\"`. When you have unexpected HTML output, look at browser page source to see the real output.

Comment: I think problem is with the function that i use. i removed the function and hyperlinks got printed!

Comment: Google "php function variable scope" You declare `$links` in the function but you don't return and "capture" the value  in another variable. Read up on fumctions, you can do some good stuff. Happy programming!

Comment: Terminus i want to return multiple values from function but i only get two and the $resultcounter value is for first iteration and $links only get first result if there is two result! Is this possible to achieve using function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put return array($links,$resultCounter);  after end of for each loop and my data was returned back correctly!